# Por que 'to_s' não está sendo sobrescrito?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, ruby, herança, sobrescrita

Em Ruby você pode sobrescrever métodos, até mesmo de classes "padrão" da linguagem. Eu só queria saber porque o código que eu fiz abaixo não sobrescreve corretamente.

```
class Oi
end

class Ola
  def to_s
    puts "Olá!"
  end
end

oi = Oi.new
ola = Ola.new

puts oi
puts ola
```

A saída é:

> ````
> #<Oi:0x000055aa6f9c1bd8> Olá!
> #<Ola:0x000055aa6f9c1b88> ```
> ````

O método `to_s` da classe `Ola` não havia sido sobrescrito? Por que ele imprime `#<Ola:0x000055aa6f9c1b88>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `to_s` deve retornar um valor do tipo *string* que faça sentido para aquele objeto e quem receber esse valor faz o que quiser com ele, por exemplo o `puts` imprimirá esse texto. Quando você manda imprimir dentro do `to_s`, além disso estar conceitualmente errado porque pode não ser o desejado uma impressão do valor no console, não está devolvendo um valor válido, não retorna um texto, o `puts` lá dentro do método faz com que o retorno seja nulo, e aí ele considera que você não tem um valor válido e continua devolvendo um valor padrão.

Retornando um valor que faça sentido tudo funciona como deveria:

```
class Oi
end

class Ola
    def to_s
        "Olá!"
    end
end
oi = Oi.new
ola = Ola.new
puts oi
puts ola
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KF39Lx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/veeaoqlp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/ToString.rb).

Comment: Seria porque a diferença no tipo de retorno impediu a sobrescrita (diferentes assinaturas)? O que a princípio pode parecer estranho dada a tipagem dinâmica do Ruby? Tentei retornando o inteiro `1` e também não sobrescreveu: https://ideone.com/qXg3V3

Comment: Ruby não tem sobrecarga. Tem que retornar o tipo correto para a intenção. Mas não sei bem porque a linguagem escolheu esse padrão quando está errado.